# Representing a set of integers with bits in C

Tags: c, data-structures, set, bitwise-operators

I got tasked to make a typedef which will represent an array of numbers from 0 to 127.

The numbers cannot repeat - it's a set of integers.

This is not good because it consumes too much data:

```
typedef struct set {
    char array[128];
} some_set;
```

as for later this data structure will be used to define different sets (`set_a`, `set_b`, `set_c`, etc.) which will be used for different operations like:

- `print_set` which will print the set
- `union_set` which combines 2 sets into a 3rd set
- `intersect_set` which will intersect 2 sets and save the data in the 3rd

Someone suggested to represent each number with a bit, but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _an array of number taken from 0 to 128_.

Comment: Are you to reflect numbers of the range between 0 and 127? Or are to represent 128 separate numbers of char range?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: @Yunnosch to reflect array of numbers range between 0 and 127, English is not my native tongue, thanks

Comment: Will each of the number be unique? I.e. any present value will not be repeated? I.e. any value is present once or never?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes they can't repeat, it's a number's set

Comment: What is the `sizeof( long long int )` in your environment? Or can you use uint128_t?

Comment: @Yunnosch it's not restricted, but given the fact that the numbers range from 0 to 127, they can't be logically more than 128 numbers total in each set

Comment: I would have sworn that I did not post that comment.. Mind reader, are you? ;-) Or just fast in reading comments I deleted or edited.... :-)

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't understand your question about the environment but i use UNIX Ubuntu for this project

Comment: Does the typedef have to do all the work? Currently I am thinking of identifying any 128 bit integer and then do some magic with bit manipulation. A typedef wouldn't even occur in that.... I.e. is your task to create an ingenious typedef or more about making an abstract datatype? I.e. a typedef accompanied by some functions for the needed operations.

Comment: @Yunnosch No the typedef is only for defining the structure as for later I will use it to maintain 6 different sets with the same attribute and do actions with them, like union, intersects etc....

Comment: Could you provide your frame? E.g. the prototypes of the functions which should be useable with the construct? And please show the output of `printf("%d\n", sizeof(long long int));`. Or state that your solution has to be platform independent.

Comment: @Yunnosch I added some examples to the discription

Comment: See [How can I use bit fields to save memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096894/how-can-i-use-bit-fields-to-save-memory) – the answers don't use bit-fields.  My code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `sets.c` and `sets.h` in the [src/so-3109-6894](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-3109-6894) sub-directory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this just with a `typedef`.

Given that, any type which contains at least 128 bits will be enough to implement this. Examples:

```
typedef uint32_t intset[4]; // array
typedef struct {uint64_t data[2];} intset; // struct containing an array
typedef uint128_t intset; // built-in 128-bit integer type
```

In addition to the `typedef`, you have to define functions that work with the data structure. For example:

```
void intset_init(intset *set);
void intset_add(intset *set, int n);
void intset_remove(intset *set, int n);
bool intset_check(intset *set, int n);
bool intset_is_empty(intset *set);
```

Each such function should use [bit-fiddling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/509868) to do its work. For example:

```
typedef uint32_t intset[4];

void intset_add(intset *set, int n)
{
    (*set)[n / 32] |= (uint32_t)1 << (n % 32);
}
```

---

It may be more efficient to pass and return the data structure by value, not by pointer. If you want this, you cannot use an array `typedef` - use any other one which is convenient.

```
typedef struct {uint64_t data[2];} intset;

intset intset_add(intset set, int n)
{
    set.data[n / 64] |= (uint64_t)1 << (n % 64);
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for acting upon the clarifications I got from OP, for using the concept I described and for giving credit. It will of course totally surprise you that I was also making an answer.