# How to declare different size variables

Tags: c, variables

Hi I want to declare a 12 bit variable in C or any "unconventional" size variable (a variable that is not in the order of 2^n). how would I do that. I looked everywhere and I couldn't find anything. If that is not possible how would you go about saving certain data in its own variable.

Comment: This is a bit too broad. Could you specify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: One way is to declare a 16-bit variable and only use the lowest 12 bits.

Comment: What do you actually try to accomplish, what is your deeper problem? That might be an XY-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is always stored in groups of bytes (8 bits each).

In C, variables can be declared of 1 byte (a "char" or 8 bits), 2 bytes (a "short" int on many computers is 16 bits), and 4 bytes (a "long" int on many computers is 32 bits).

On a more advanced level, you are looking for "bitfields".

See this perhaps: [bitfield discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c)

Comment: 1) A byte is not necessarily 8 bits. 2) C does not require octets either. A `char` is the same a s byte, but - see 1 3) Integer types may include padding bits, thus in principle an `int` with 17 used bits is possible. It may or may not contain padding, this depends on the width of a byte/`char`..

Comment: If you comment on my comment, use `@<name>`, otherwise your comment can get through unnoticed. About the text: What does please you? If you think I am wrong, provide a reference to the corresponding section in the standard.

Comment: @Olaf so what are the top 3 selling systems that implement non-8-bit bytes???  :-)

Comment: You have any knowledge about DSPs and custom CPUs in FPGAs? There are quite some which have 16 or even 24 bit words only. That is not a matter of quantity. C is a standardised language and that standard is very clear about the terms.

Comment: @Olaf My understanding is that FPGAs are programmed in HDL.  But rather writing for them in (c-like) OpenCL I suppose proves your esoteric point.  Someone who is _asking_ about unconventional bit-widths is unlikely to know anything about FPGAs.

Comment: I wrote about "custom CPUs in FPGAs". There are some IP cores which do not necessarily have 8 bit addressable unit size, but can be configured (within some range), according to the application. Anyway, it is enough to stick to the C standard - which you apparently try to distract from.

Answer (score 4):

Use a bitfield:

```
struct {
   unsigned int twelve_bits: 12;
} wrapper;
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Ada, C has no way to specify types with a limited range of values.  C relies on predefined types with implementation defined characteristics, but with certain guarantees:

- Types `short` and `int` are guaranteed by the standard to hold at least 16 bits, you can use either one to hold your 12 bit values, signed or unsigned.
- Similarly, type `long` is guaranteed to hold at least 32 bits and type `long long` at least 64 bits.  Choose the type that is large enough for your purpose.
- Types `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` and their unsigned counterparts defined in `<stdint.h>` have more precise semantics but might not be available on all systems. Types `int_least8_t`, `int_least16_t`, `int_least32_t` and `int_least64_t` are guaranteed to be available, as well as similar `int_fastXX_t` types, but they are not used very often, probably because the names are somewhat cumbersome.
- Finally, you can use bit-fields for any bit counts from `1` to `64`, but these are only available as struct members. bit-fields of size one should be declared as `unsigned`.

Comment: The `intNleast_t` and `intNfast_t` and their unsigned counterparts are guaranteed to be available.

Comment: @Olaf: I edited the answer for completeness, but these names are obviously not very friendly.

Comment: Agreed about their names; they are just too long. But still they exist. Anyway - to me, it is not clear what OP actually wants to accomplish and mean by _declare_ here. The available variable sizes can be found very easily.

Comment: @Olaf: maybe a side effect of some Misra-like coding convention that states *variables should be defined with the smallest type that accommodates their value set*.  A counterproductive constraint in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm... I was lucky until now not having to conform to such stuff (MISRA is a good reading, but a bad idea just to blindly follow). That rule especially can increase code-size because of required sign/zero extension code. I also learned to avoid the standard types (`int`, etc.=. But the older I get the more I think they might actually not that bad to be used if the guaranteed minimum range is sufficient. Of course, if you need a specific size, `(u)intN_t` are the logical choice.