# What is a non-field member of a structure or union?

Tags: c

From K&R The C Programming Language:

> **A non-field member of a structure or union** may have any object type.
>
> **A field member** (which need  not  have  a  declarator  and  thus  may  be  unnamed)  has  type  int ,  unsigned  int ,  or signed  int ,
>   and is interpreted as an object of integral type of the specified
>   length in bits;  whether  an  int   field  is  treated  as  signed  is
>   implementation-dependent.
>
> ...
>
> **A  non-field member of a structure** is aligned at an addressing boundary depending on its type;  therefore, there may be unnamed holes
>   in a structure.

1. I thought that the members of a structure or union are called its
   fields. So what is a non-field member of a structure or union? How
   is it different from a field member?
2. Can you explain "A non-field member of a structure or union may have
   any object type" with some examples?
3. Does the second sentence in the quote mean that a field member can
   only have type int, unsigned int, or signed int?
4. The last sentence in the quote mentions that a non-field member is
   aligned. Is a field member aligned? If not, how is a field member
   stored in memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A field member is nowadays called a [**bit field**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) member:

```
int i : 3;      // named bit-field member
int : 5;        // unnamed bit-field member
int j;          // non-bit-field member
const char *s;  // non-bit-field member, non-integer type
```

[When to use bit-fields in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c)