# Is ":" operator equivalent to an assignment operator "= "?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I am new to C coding and I ran into ":" in the following structure

```
struct __tag131
{                                                          /* Bit Access       */
unsigned char  P0P6:1;                                 /* P0P6             */
unsigned char  P1P6:1;                                 /* P1P6             */
unsigned char  P2P6:1;                                 /* P2P6             */
unsigned char  P3P6:1;                                 /* P3P6             */
unsigned char  :2;                                     /* Reserved Bits    */
unsigned char  TBP6:1;                                 /* TBP6             */
unsigned char  MKP6:1;                                 /* MKP6             */
unsigned char  :4;                                     /* Reserved Bits    */
unsigned char  RFP6:1;                                 /* RFP6             */
unsigned char  :2;                                     /* Reserved Bits    */
unsigned char  CTP6:1;                                 /* CTP6             */
};
```

What is the use of ":" ? Is it even a operator ? I know what a unsigned char 'type' is but what is unsigned char :2 ? Please explain.

Comment: Google bitfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit field in C allows a compressed form of information.   The number after the colon describes the number of bits which are allowed for storage.

```
1 bit => 0,1   (or -1,0 )
2 bits => 0,3  (or -2,1 )
3 bits => 0,7  (or -4,3 )
```

The data is slower to access, but uses less space.

Comment: Are the values in parantheses for the signed datatypes? In that case there is a `(or -1,0)` missing for 1 bit.

Comment: @mch Sharp eye.

Comment: Hmm - I had guessed they would disallow 1 bit signed)

Answer (score 2):

No, the ":" are bitfields.  You can read about them more at:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm
- [When to use bit-fields in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c)