# : symbol in c structure and it uses

Tags: c++, c

Whats does the : symbol means in c structure.
The code below supposed to show output 12 (size of int=4,size of structure=sum of each structure member)

But it is showing 8 as output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
int bit1:20;
int bit2:1;
int bit30:30;
} bits;

int main()
{
printf("%d",sizeof(bits));
}
```

But when i change the value

```
int bits30:30;
```

Into

```
int bits30:40;
```

It is showing an error,what is the use of : in c structure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c

Comment: I found the linked questions by googling for "stackoverflow c struct colon".

Comment: BTW, since you tagged as C++, you don't need `typedef struct` in C++.

Comment: When dealing with bits, you should prefer `unsigned int` to `int`.  You don't want to mess with the interpretations of the sign bit.