# Can or should I make bools bit fields?

Tags: c, struct, boolean, bit-fields

Is this legal or recommended? I read that you should only use integer types as bitfields, but does this apply to boolean types? Is this OK, or is this bad practice or undefined behavior somehow?

```
struct MyStruct {
    // ...
    bool SomeBooleanProperty:1;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: it does not matter as bool can one have two integer values which perfectly fits 1 bit bitfield

Comment: `bool` is an integer type.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have a bitfield of type `bool` and this is explicitly stated in the C17 standard at 6.7.2.1 (5) (note that `_Bool` is the same as `bool`).

Comment: Though I have heard that `bool` and `unsigned char` have subtle differences

Comment: @NateEldredge OK cool

Comment: The differences have to do with assigning values other than `true` and `false`, but you're not going to do that anyway, right?

Comment: As far as the advisability, it's subject to all the same pros and cons of using bitfields in general, which are discussed ad nauseum elsewhere, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c/24934836#24934836

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can ... I make bools bit fields?

Yes.  It is one of 3 well defined choices.

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted. C17dr § 6.7.2.1 5

---

> .... should I make bools bit fields?

Yes, if it makes code more clear.

Note: this is one place to not use `int x:1` as it is implementation defined if `x` has values [0,1] or [-1,0]. Use `signed int x:1` or `unsigned x:1` or `_Bool x:1` for [-1,0], [0,1], [0,1] respectively.

For `x:1`, `bool` does have a clearer functionally specification than `signed int` when assigning an out-of-range value. See [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107635/can-or-should-i-make-bools-bit-fields/68107923?noredirect=1#comment120377739_68107923).  For `unsigned`, just the LSbit is copied.

Comment: Note that `_Bool` and the int versions behave differently, e.g. `x = 2;` will produce a true `_Bool` but zero for the other types

Comment: @M.M Agree zero for  `bool` and  `unsinged`.  Likely   zero for `signed int` - yet that is an implementation defined conversions.  That point does give `bool` an edge.